# Why is Xcode telling me to add .map { $0.rawValue } when I can just do ?.rawValue?

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, option-type

I have this code:

```
enum Enum: String {
    case A = "A"
}

let s: String? = Enum(rawValue: "A")
```

Of course, it does not compile. Normally, I fix it this way:

```
let s: String? = Enum(rawValue: "A")?.rawValue
```

However, Xcode says that I should add `.map { $0.rawValue }`:

[image]

This is weird because clearly, Xcode is aware that accessing `rawValue` can turn `Enum` into a `String`. But why does it suggest to do it using `map`? Why not just access it directly?

I thought Xcode would think this way:

> I've got a string constant on the left and an enum whose raw value is string. The types are not compatible, but I know `rawValue` can turn the enum into a string. I'll just suggest the user to add `?.rawValue`!

What is Xcode's "thinking process" behind this?

P.S. My intention here is to check whether `"A"` is a valid raw value for an enum. If it is, assign it to `s`, otherwise assign `nil`. I know this is not very practical, but I'm just concerned with Xcode's behaviour.

Comment: Just tried it on Playground, your initial fix works there. Curious how XCode is "Thinking" using `map` would fix the problem.

Comment: Really, I'm just amazed that Xcode is smart enough to even provide a fix-it for that in the first place.

Comment: Please don't bother Xcode with that counterproductive stuff that you – the developer – should know at compile time. Enum cases cannot change at runtime so a potential crash clearly reveals a developer error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

João Marcelo Souza's third answer is exactly correct. `.map` is the Optional safe-unwrapping method *par excellence*. `Enum(rawValue: "A").map{$0.rawValue}` *is* `Enum(rawValue: "A")?.rawValue`.

The problem is merely that we are all so used to using the second one (syntactic sugar) that we forget that the first one is how the Swift compiler actually thinks, under the hood.

Example:

```
var i : [Int]? = [7]
i.map {$0.count} // 1
i?.count // 1

i = nil
i.map {$0.count} // nil
i?.count // nil
```

Comment: I would like to point out that "map" is part of optional and the Enum init returns an optional. rawValue is part of the enum (RawRepresentable) and nothing to do with the optional. The map has nothing to do with the enum.

Answer (score 7):

It's not specific to `Enum`. In fact, all `Optional` instances implement the [`map` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map):

```
let possibleNumber: Int? = Int("4")
let possibleSquare = possibleNumber.map { $0 * $0 }
print(possibleSquare) // Prints "Optional(16)"
```

I am not sure why Xcode suggests that instead of just `.rawValue` but I can think of a few possible reasons:

1. Alphabetical order.
2. You may want to perform some operation on the unwrapped value.
3. Maybe `foo?.bar` is just syntax sugar for `foo.map { $0.bar }`

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by alphabetical order?

Comment: Alphabetical order: (m)ap is before (r)awValue. But that's naive. 3 is my best bet.